# Can you use split button dropdown inside a dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Having an issue with a drop-down inside a dropdown login menu using the twitter bootstrap framework. The second dropdown for the login box is not working. Is it possible to include a split button dropdown inside a dropdown like in the example below.

See this fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/DMWFj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you clicked on second drop-down button, jQuery plugin "bootstrap-dropdown.js" hides **all** elements with class "open".

You need to edit file "bootstrap-dropdown.js" (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js) and rewrite function clearMenus().

Find next code in this file:

```
function clearMenus() {
    getParent($(toggle))
      .removeClass('open')
}
```

and replace it with:

```
function clearMenus($this) {
    getParent($this)
      .removeClass('open')
}
```

Find line clearMenus() near:

```
  , toggle: function (e) {
  var $this = $(this)
    , $parent
    , isActive

  if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

  $parent = getParent($this)

  isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

  clearMenus() // here
```

Replace line `clearMenus()` with `clearMenus($this)`.

Here jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BMBc3/

Comment: Thank you for the info and the fix. If I change this will I see any adverse effects?